# MATLAB reading specific fields of a pdb file

Tags: matlab, coordinates

I have to be coding this in MATLAB. My problem is I would like to extract coordinates of certain atoms corresponding only to some residues in a PDB file. For example, I  would like to extract coordinates of CA atoms of all alanine present in the PDB file. I tried using find(strcmp(atoms,'CA')) but it gives me all CA atoms and not CA of Alanine only. How can solve this problem in MATLAB? Kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

All I know about `PDB` files is what I've read today at http://www.wwpdb.org/index and here (http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/v3.3.html).

I've used the example provided by MatLab help to read the `PDB` file.

According to the structure of the data read from the `PDB` file and the description of the file format, it seems to me that the data you are looking for are contained in the `Model.Atom` field.

More precisely (`glf` is the name of the struct read by `pdbread` function):

```
gfl.Model.Atom(:).AtomName
gfl.Model.Atom(:).resName
gfl.Model.Atom(:).X
gfl.Model.Atom(:).Y
gfl.Model.Atom(:).Z
```

If so, in order to identify the atoms "CA" of `Alcaline` you can use a combination of `find` and `strcmp` functions as follows:

```
pos=find(strcmp({gfl.Model.Atom(:).AtomName},'CA') & ...
   strcmp({gfl.Model.Atom(:).resName},'ALA'))
```

The output array `pos` contains the indices of the Atoms you are looking for.

To extract the coordinate, you can then use that indices as follows:

```
X=[gfl.Model.Atom(pos).X]
Y=[gfl.Model.Atom(pos).Y]
Z=[gfl.Model.Atom(pos).Z]
```

You can make more "general" the code by defining "Atom name" and Residue name as parameter.

In the following, you can find the complete script, based on the example file privided by MatLab.

```
% Generate a PDB file (example from MatLab help)
gfl = getpdb('1GFL','TOFILE','1gfl.pdb')
% Read the PDB file
gfl = pdbread('1gfl.pdb')


% Define the Atom Name
atom_name='CA';
% Define the Residue Name
res_name='ALA';
% Search for the couple "Atom name - Residue Name"
pos=find(strcmp({gfl.Model.Atom(:).AtomName},atom_name) & ...
   strcmp({gfl.Model.Atom(:).resName},res_name))

% Extract the coordinates of the Atoms matching the search criteria
X=[gfl.Model.Atom(pos).X]
Y=[gfl.Model.Atom(pos).Y]
Z=[gfl.Model.Atom(pos).Z]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.